Rust use impl's generic argument for trait's function generic argument
I have a trait
pub trait FromContext {
    fn from_context<T>(context: Context<T>) -> Result<Self>;
}

and I would like to have an implementation of that trait like this
pub struct State<T>(pub T);

impl<T> FromContext for State<T> {
    fn from_context<T>(context: Context<T>) -> Result<Self> {
        Result::Ok(State(context.state))
    }
}

but I get the error
error[E0403]: the name `T` is already used for a generic parameter in this item's generic parameters

I also tried
impl<T1> FromContext for State<T1> {
    fn from_context<T2>(context: Context<T2>) -> Result<Self> {
        Result::Ok(State(context.state))
    }
}

but then I get
error[E0308]: mismatched types

Is there anyway to tell Rust T1 and T2 should be equal?

T would need to be a parameter on the trait, not the method.

pub trait FromContext {
    fn from_context<T>(context: Context<T>) -> Result<Self>;
}

This trait's contract is that from_context can be called with any possible T whatsoever and this will produce a Result<Self>.  If instead you want only one T to work, chosen by the implementation, you have two options.
First, you could use a generic trait.  Just move the generic type parameter from the trait method to the trait itself.
pub trait FromContext<T> {
    fn from_context(context: Context<T>) -> Result<Self>;
}

Now you can impl<T> FromContext<T> for State<T> and all the types will line up.  The benefit of this approach is that you can implement FromContext<T> multiple times on the same type for different Ts.
(Sidebar: Given this definition, perhaps you can ditch your trait and instead use TryFrom<Context<T>>?)
The second approach is to use associated types.
pub trait FromContext {
    type ContextType;

    fn from_context(context: Context<Self::ContextType>) -> Result<Self>;
}

This limits the number of implementations per type to one, but can be beneficial in other ways.  In particular, blanket implementations involving generic traits such as FromContext<T> can get tricky because types can implement this trait multiple times, whereas you don't have this problem with a non-generic FromContext.
Implementing this trait would look like this:
impl<T> FromContext for State<T> {
    type ContextType = T;

    fn from_context<T>(context: Context<T>) -> Result<Self> {
        Result::Ok(State(context.state))
    }
}

